# Devise Accept Nested Attributes for Member problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to have profile model in a devise Member model as a nested attribute.

Here's my Member model:

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  attr_accessible :username, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :profile_attributes

  has_one :profile
  has_many :bio_news_posts
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile

end
```

I can ensure that the profile object for the Member has been created before saving the Member object. I enter all the necessary values, still I get this error at the output:

```
Email cannot be blank.
```

When I see in the terminal, all the fields have values, still I get this message.

And I see this warning in the terminal:

```
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: email
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `:email` to the `attr_accessible` call

Comment: I have basically been a victim of Murphy's law. I changed the devise email to username, then decided to revert back to email, but apparently forgot change at this one place. Thanks a lot, that works.

Comment: No worries, I was only able to recognize it so quickly because I've done it myself plenty of times. :)